ggsankey - how to add proportions or absolute counts for each node?
I have a dataset:
Baseline,Week1,Week2,Week3
1,0,0,0
0,0,0,0
1,1,1,0
0,0,0,0
1,0,0,0
0,0,0,0
1,0,0,0
1,,0,0
1,0,0,0
1,1,1,1
1,1,1,1
1,1,1,1
1,1,1,1
0,0,1,0
1,0,0,0
1,1,1,1
0,,0,0
0,0,0,0
1,1,1,1
1,1,1,
0,,,0
0,0,0,0
1,1,0,0
0,1,1,0
1,1,1,1
1,0,0,0
1,0,0,
1,0,0,
1,0,1,0
1,1,1,1
0,0,0,0
1,1,1,
0,1,1,1
0,0,1,0
0,0,0,0
1,0,1,1
1,1,1,
1,1,0,0
1,0,1,
1,,0,1
1,0,1,

There are 4 time points (Baseline, Week1, Week2, and Week3), at each time point each patient (individual rows) had been diagnosed to either be positive (1) or negative (0).
I have made a sankey diagram:
df <- sankey_proportions %>%
  make_long(Baseline, Week1, Week2, Week3)

ggplot(df, aes(x = x, 
               next_x = next_x, 
               node = node, 
               next_node = next_node,
               fill = factor(node), 
               label = node)) +
  geom_sankey(flow.alpha = 0.5, 
              node.color = 0.5, 
              width = 0.05) +
  scale_fill_viridis_d(alpha = 0.7) +
  theme_sankey(base_size = 10)


I would like to have shown absolute counts or proportions in each node, I guess the function has to calculate it for itself to make the plot, but did not find any of this in the vignette.

The counts are already computed under the hood and stored in a column freq which you can access using ggplot2::after_stat():
library(ggplot2)
library(ggsankey)

df <- sankey_proportions |>
  make_long(Baseline, Week1, Week2, Week3)

p <- ggplot(df, aes(
  x = x,
  next_x = next_x,
  node = node,
  next_node = next_node,
  fill = factor(node),
  label = node
)) +
  geom_sankey(
    flow.alpha = 0.5,
    node.color = 0.5,
    width = 0.05
  ) +
  scale_fill_viridis_d(alpha = 0.7) +
  theme_sankey(base_size = 10)

p +
  geom_sankey_label(
    aes(
      label = after_stat(freq),
      color = after_stat(I(ifelse(node %in% 0, "white", "black")))
    ),
    show.legend = FALSE
  )


And if you want to proportions you can can compute them inside after_stat() using e.g. ave() like so:
p +
  geom_sankey_label(
    aes(
      label = after_stat(
        scales::percent(ave(freq, x, FUN = \(x) x / sum(x)))
      ),
      color = after_stat(I(ifelse(node %in% 0, "white", "black")))
    ),
    show.legend = FALSE
  )


DATA
sankey_proportions <- structure(list(Baseline = c(
  1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L,
  1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L,
  1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L
), Week1 = c(
  0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, NA, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L,
  1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, NA, 0L, 1L, 1L, NA, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L,
  0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, NA, 0L
), Week2 = c(
  0L,
  0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L,
  0L, 1L, 1L, NA, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L,
  1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L
), Week3 = c(
  0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L,
  0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, NA, 0L,
  0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, NA, NA, 0L, 1L, 0L, NA, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, NA,
  0L, NA, 1L, NA
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -41L))

